# Access Raspberry Pi web server from outside LAN takes me to router

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I am trying to access my Raspberry Pi server from outside (using no-ip), but it takes me to the router page. My setup:

- Raspberry has a static ip (I can access it from inside LAN using it's local ip address)
- I setup and use a no-ip account so I don't have to care about dynamic router address. Downloaded noip client to Raspberry too.
- Tried port forwarding port 80 and adding rules to allow incoming connections.
  I read a lot of similar answers and posts but still unable to find the proper configuration
- Router is Comtrend vr3032u

Comment: On your router management pages go to `Management` -> `Access Control` -> `Service Access`. A table of approximately 6 protocols will be listed. What does `HTTP` service say under `Current`?

Answer (score 0):

Check your router settings to see if you can turn off the management web interface from the WAN side of the network (i.e. do not run the webserver on port 80 of your publicly routable IP address. Since you are seeing the management interface when you try to request port 80 from the WAN side that means that the management interface is blocking the port forwarding rule. Most likely this is happening in the firewall, essentially the rule for "Accept Port 80" comes before the rule for "Forward Port 80".

I am not familiar with that specific router you have, so I can't help specifically with the steps to take in your web interface. It doesn't look like your router is supported by DD-WRT. If you are open to getting a new router, take a look at [those that are supported by DD-WRT](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices) as it will give you much more flexibility and stability than commercial router firmware. Not to mention the community support for the open source firmware distributions is much better than for commercial firmware.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not restricted to port 80 you could use another port. This would prevent other people from stumbling onto your Raspberry Pi giving you a bit more protection.

In your port forwarding you can have it listening on any other port and then redirect it to your Raspberry Pi's IP and port 80. I have attached an example what I have done with my router.

[image]

- Service Name=Anything (for your own reference only)
- Port Range=Port to use on the outside
- Local IP=The IP address of the Raspberry PI server on your own internal network
- Local Port=The port which the Raspberry PI server is listening
- Protocol=TCP

I choose the incoming port as 88 and forward it to the Raspberry Pi's IP and Port 80.

So on the outside you would use address

> http://your.domain:88/